# Recover data after reformat

Tags: windows

Is it possible to recover data after a hard drive has been reformatted and windows reinstalled on the drive? As a friend has forgot to back up some important word documents.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/301757/128794  , which incidentally, was closed as a duplicate :)  In any case check out those questions for possible solutions to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The simplest way to understand a reformat is to think of a hard drive as a book, the folders are chapters and files are pages. Windows explorer is just a contents page. So, all a reformat does is remove the contents page. And since you can't see the contents, you can't get access the pages (files / folders), but this doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

However, since you've re-installed Windows, it is possible it's overwritten some of your 'old' pages (files /folders).

I suggest a search for "free hard drive recovery" into a [search engine like this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=free%20hard%20drive%20recovery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible. I'd recommend [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), as it is free and has an extensive featureset. It also works on most OS's.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible.

There's a similar question on *Android Enthusiasts* that covers just this:

[Data Recovery - How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/data-recovery-how-to-restore-deleted-formatted-files-on-hd-micro-sd-card)

You can also search for [file carving](https://www.google.de/search?q=file%20carving) or have a look at the [forensics wiki](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Data_Recovery)